# I keep getting error:"Please wait until the current program is finished uninstalling or being changed."

Tags: windows-7, uninstall

I have Windows 7. I am unable to uninstall many unwanted programs because I keep getting an error message:

> Wait until the current program is finished uninstalling.

Then another message appears:

> Messages file:Program Files\PC Tools Security\BDT\uninstall is missing.Please correct the problem or obtain a new copy of the program.

I am getting very frustrated because this has been going on for 
a week and I cannot uninstall many unwanted programs from Windows 7. I am a senior and not very computer savvy so I would appreciate any detailed instructions what to do step-by-step, please.

Comment: Just a guess here, but maybe the program from PC Tools Security is trying to run every time you attempt to uninstall a program...and there's something wrong with it. You could contact that vendor for support.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to manually uninstall the program, following the following steps ([Source](http://toolbarcollection.com/toolbar_detail.php?toolbar_id=900&name=PC%20Tools%20Browser%20Defender)):

**Step 1: Open the Registry Editor**

Hold down the Windows key on your keyboard and press the "R" button. Type in "regedit" and hit "Enter" to gain access to the Registry Editor.

**Step 2: Locate the toolbar location in your registry.**

Look in the left pane and locate "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Toolbar."
You will see a list of GUID. Locate {472734EA-242A-422B-ADF8-83D1E48CC825} in the right pane .

**Step3: Delete**

Delete the GUID key by right clicking on it and hitting *Delete*.

**Step 4:Find the right DLL that the toolbar use.**

Find and double-click "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{472734EA-242A-422B-ADF8-83D1E48CC825}\InprocServer32" in the left pane. On the right panel, click on (Default)
{472734EA-242A-422B-ADF8-83D1E48CC825}
{472734EA-242A-422B-ADF8-83D1E48CC825}

**Step 5: Find the toolbar name**

Do like step 4 ,
Find and double-click "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{472734EA-242A-422B-ADF8-83D1E48CC825} , on the right Panel click on Default

---

If this doesn't work, try [deleting](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000743.htm) the entire folder *Program Files\PC Tools Security*.

If you have any more questions or this solution doesn't work, feel free to ask.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately you question leaves far too much questions open to write a step-by-step guide.

Up in front, please always remember the following sentence:

> When facing very complex problems, always consider if a "start from
>   scrach" could be much faster than attempting to solve the problems by
>   starting from scratch than by trying to modify the existing
>   configuration.

I suggest a fresh installation of your windows in this case because a backup of your personal files plus a new installation only costs about 3 hours instead of potentially weeks trying to get rid of unwanted software

So, why spending hours of investigations into programs faults instead of just backing up the data you really need and do a reinstallation of windows?

The basic steps to really investigate the problems with all your unwanted programs are:

- reboot and retry uninstallation
- was the software you want to remove just part of something bigger? - if yes, try to uninstall the "umbrella" sofware
- go to Start-Control Panel-Programs and try to uninstall all the stuff you want to get rid off from there
- check if there are any "uninstall.exe" files located at the installation directories of your unwanted software
- run a malware detection/removal tool

If those tipps do not satisfy your requirements, please add some more details to your question by editing your question instead of commenting my answer.
 -

Comment: It can get kind of exhausting to reinstall windows with every little problem you have. I don't quite agree, that it's faster to start from scratch than trying to correct existing complex problems - Just imagine you'd have to start from scratch while encountering a bug in a close to finish software you're writing.

Comment: @MetaColon you are right, i'll correct the statement.

Comment: By the way, "too many unwanted programs installed" is the perfect right time to reinstall any OS. For a typical user and also most admins this means that he did not do a reinstallation for many years so the user is experiencing a massive degradation of OS performance. Most people tend to buy new hardware instead of refreshing the OS even if refreshing is all they need.